# insertSublayer atIndex puts things on top of other layers

Tags: objective-c, view, insert, indexing, layer

I'm using ColorBGView and calling methods inside of it to make gradients. But if I attach two to my layer, it overlaps everything else I attach afterward, and I don't understand why.

```
        CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [ColorBGView pinkSky1];
        bgLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        [viewController.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];

    //If I insert this sublayer (even at a lower index) 
    //it overlaps everything I attach afterward

        CAGradientLayer *bgLayer2 = [ColorBGView darkCave];
        bgLayer2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        [viewController.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer2 atIndex:-10];    

        // add custom view

        parallaxView = [[ParallaxView alloc] init];
        parallaxView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        [viewController.view insertSubview:parallaxView atIndex:1];

        [parallaxView release];
```

Comment: Did you try using `-insertSublayer:below:` instead of a negative index?   atIndex: is supposed to refer to the place in the array, not the zValue.

Comment: Thanks gaige, I tried below and above. Below makes the first sublayer be on top of everything. Above makes the second sublayer be on top of everything.

Comment: So it's still putting the gradient on top of everything added after it.